# Graph QL Search Result Computed Field

Tags: solr, jss, content-search, graphql

I have started to look at using `Graph QL` for search using the endpoint that comes out the box with `Sitecore 10.1`. I've read that the results are based on an item but had lazy loading eg. You have indexed a field. How does this work in regards to computed fields, how do I see this as part of my results set?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1.**

Add a new config file to your `{webroot folder}/App_Config/Include` area to include an `/api/search` `GraphQL` endpoint:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
<sitecore>
    <api>
        <!--
    Define the app's Sitecore GraphQL API endpoint
    Note: this can be removed if you are not using GraphQL.
    Note: the endpoint must be defined both for integrated and connected type GraphQL queries.
  -->
        <GraphQL>
            <endpoints>
                <searchGraphQLEndpoint url="/api/search" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.DatabaseAwareGraphQLEndpoint, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.NetFxHost" resolve="true">
                    <url>$(url)</url>

                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <enableSubscriptions>true</enableSubscriptions>

                    <!-- lock down the endpoint when deployed to content delivery -->
                    <graphiql role:require="ContentDelivery">false</graphiql>
                    <enableSchemaExport role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableSchemaExport>
                    <enableStats role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableStats>
                    <enableCacheStats role:require="ContentDelivery">false</enableCacheStats>
                    <disableIntrospection role:require="ContentDelivery">true</disableIntrospection>

                    <schema hint="list:AddSchemaProvider">
                        <content type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.ContentSchemaProvider, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">
                            <!-- scope typed template generation to just this app's templates -->
                            <templates type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.TemplateGeneration.Filters.StandardTemplatePredicate, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">
                                <database>context</database>
                                <paths hint="list:AddIncludedPath">
                                    <templates>/sitecore/templates/Project/search</templates>
                                </paths>
                                <fieldFilter type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.TemplateGeneration.Filters.StandardFieldFilter, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">
                                    <exclusions hint="raw:AddFilter">
                                        <!--
                                        Remove system fields from the API (e.g. __Layout) to keep the schema lean
                                        -->
                                        <exclude name="__*" />
                                    </exclusions>
                                </fieldFilter>
                            </templates>

                            <queries hint="raw:AddQuery">
                                <!-- enable querying on items via this API -->
                                <query name="item" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Queries.ItemQuery, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />
                                <query name="search" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Queries.SearchQuery, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content"/>
                            </queries>

                            <fieldTypeMapping ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/content/fieldTypeMappings/standardTypeMapping" />
                        </content>
                    </schema>

                    <!-- Enables the 'jss' graph nodes that are preformatted to use with JSS rendering components, and the datasource resolving queries for JSS -->
                    <extenders hint="list:AddExtender">
                        <layoutExtender type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.GraphQL.JssExtender, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.GraphQL" resolve="true" />
                    </extenders>

                    <!-- Determines the security of the service. 'publicService' is open to anonymous access, but requires an SSC API key. -->
                    <security ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/security/publicService" />

                    <!-- Determines how performance is logged for the service. Defaults are defined in Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.config -->
                    <performance ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/performance/standard" />
                </searchGraphQLEndpoint>
            </endpoints>
        </GraphQL>
    </api>
</sitecore>
```

**Step 2.**

Open GraphQL Playground in a browser window and visit the new `/api/search` URL `https://{your-sitecore-host}/api/search/ui?sc_apikey={your-api-key}`

**Step 3.**

Insert this query on the left that contains the requested computed index field name you want to retrieve (in my case it was **searchcontent_txm**). Please note, that this field is requested outside the item{} block, as inside you can only request for Sitecore item fields.

```
    query Search($rootItem: String!, $keyword: String!, $pageSize: Int!) {
  search(
    rootItem: $rootItem
    fieldsEqual:[
        { name: "searchcontent_txm", value: $keyword}
      ]
    first: $pageSize
    latestVersion: false
  ) {
    results {
      items{
        item {
            id
            name
          path
          url
          navigationTitle: field (name:"navigationTitle") {
            value
          }
          description: field (name:"description") {
            value
          }
        }
        searchcontent: field(name:"searchcontent_txm")
        score
      }
      totalCount
        pageInfo {
        endCursor
          hasPreviousPage
          hasNextPage
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 4.**
Give your query some input parameters, e.g.:

```
{
  "rootItem": "/sitecore/content/your-website/home",
  "keyword": "cinnamon",
  "pageSize": 5
}
```

Execute your query and see your results :)

Comment: I'm curious if anyone has had luck implementing this against the XM Cloud GraphQL Search Query as the `results` don't allow for `items`